# JSF 2 get index row datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I want to know how to get an row index of a datable, my code is

```
<p:dataTable 
    id="idDataTableItemArticulo" 
    var="articuloEspecificado" 
    value="#{ordenIngresoBean.oiu.articuloEspecificadoModel}"
    paginator="true" 
    rows="5"  
    rowIndexVar="row" 
    paginatorPosition="bottom"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
    rowsPerPageTemplate="5"  
    emptyMessage="Lista de Proveedores vacia" 
    editable="true" 
    editMode="cell">  

    <p:column 
        width="25px;" 
        style="text-align:center;">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputLabel value="Nro"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{row+1}" />

    </p:column>

    <p:column width="70px;" style="text-align:center;">  

        <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Nro de Serie" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <p:inputText 
            id="idInNroSerie" 
            value="#{articuloEspecificado.numeroSerie}" 
            size="15" 
            onclick="this.select();"
            required="#{not empty param[bndGuardar.clientId]}" 
            requiredMessage="Ingrese Serie">
            <p:clientValidator event="keyup"/>
        </p:inputText>  
        <p:message for="idInNroSerie" display="text"/>

    </p:column>  

    <p:column width="70px;" style="text-align:center;" >  

        <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Codigo de Barras" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <p:inputText 
            value="#{articuloEspecificado.nroCodigoBarras}" 
            size="15" 
            onclick="this.select();"/>  

    </p:column>

    <p:column width="70px;" style="text-align:center;" headerText="Estado">  

        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{articuloEspecificado.estadoUsoArticulo.nombre}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{articuloEspecificado.codigoEstado}" style="width:100%">

                    <f:selectItems 
                        value="#{ordenIngresoBean.oiu.lstEstadoUsoArticulo}" 
                        var="eua" 
                        itemLabel="#{eua.nombre}" 
                        itemValue="#{eua}" />

                    <p:ajax 
                        event="change" 
                        listener="#{ordenIngresoBean.seleccionarEstado}">

                        <f:setPropertyActionListener 
                            value="#{row}" 
                            target="#{ordenIngresoBean.oiu.index}" />

                    </p:ajax>

                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>

    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

I get the row index in the event of the selectOneMenu of the celleditor.

The method in the bean is :

```
public void seleccionarEstado(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    System.out.println(" *** seleccionarEstado *** ");
    System.out.println("Index: "+oiu.getIndex());
}
```

and the object oiu is :

```
public class OrdenIngresoUtil implements Serializable { 

private boolean lstArticuloEspecificadoVacia;
private Integer cantidad;
private Integer idSerie;
private Integer indexArticuloAlmacen;
private Integer index;
private String nroSerie;
private String numero; ..... more attributes and setter and getter

}
```

but I don't get the value of the row, it is null, Why?

Thanks

Comment: what's the managed bean scope?

Comment: did you want to get value of the selected row from your datatable ?

Comment: yes, I want to get the index for getting the object of this row

Comment: selection doesn't work with the event of selectOneMenu, so the object is always null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not elegant but may solve your problem.

```
public void seleccionarEstado(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    String x = ((HtmlSelectOneMenu)event.getSource()).getClientId();        
    System.out.println(x.split(":")[2]);
}
```

Notice that x will return something like (names may vary since these ids are generated)

```
j_idt6:idDataTableItemArticulo:0:j_idt19
                              ^^^
```

And you're interested in the index above.